# Merge svn branch with old untracked code

Tags: git, svn, version-control, versioning

i have working svn repository. Also i have branch made from old and untracked code. Unfortunately i need to merge both together. What would be best tool to do so. Would it be easier to migrate svn repository to git an then merge that untracked code. 
What tools you suggest to use. I will have very big job, so i want to prepare well.

Thank you!
Raspizdyay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that to apply changes, you need to know what changed. A single tree with no VC data has no such history information.

You will need to figure out what historical version your branch was branched from. I don't know of tools to help with this. One approach would be to compare your branch with each revision, find which ones produce the smallest diff and do not conflict, and then look at those for which is most sensible (e.g. not removing features). You can reduce the comparisons needed by doing a binary search, if you are able to recognize 'definitely older' and 'definitely newer' code by eye.

This would be easier to automate and faster to run using Git, but still *possible* in Subversion.